# Does using interfaces forces to implement interfaces return types?

Tags: delphi, interface

When using interfaces, are the implementing class methods forced to return interfaces, or is there a way to return objects?

An example will clarify:

**in unit EmployeeIntf:**

```
IEmployee = interface(IInterface)
  function CoWorker: IEmployee; // We dont know anything about TEmployee here
end;
```

**in unit Employee:**

```
uses EmployeeIntf;
...

TEmployee = class(TObject, IEmployee)
public
  function CoWorker: IEmployee; // Returns an error if set to TEmployee
end;
```

Current code stops on a compiler error if the method returns a TEmployee: E2211 Declaration of 'CoWorker' differs of declaration in interface IEmployee (using Delphi 2010)

Is the TEmployee.CoWorker method forced to return an interface, or is there a way to return a TEmployee instead, as far as the TEmployee is a IEmployee?

If only interfaces are allowed in this case, what are the OO design reasons for that?

[Edit]

- As asked by many contributors, I dont need ref counting on TEmployee and would like to isolate the above question from any ref counting consideration.
- The background of this question is a need to use a very limited set of public functions of TEmployee in an external component (in a separate package). I can't simply import the 'Employee' unit in the package because of too many uneeded dependencies in uses sections, so I'm looking for a loosely coupling solution.

Thanks,

Comment: Judging from your comments to some of the answers, you should update the question to provide the extra information given in those comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the compiler happy by introducing a method resolution clause:

```
type
  TEmployee = class(TInterfacedObject, IEmployee)
    function IEmployee.CoWorker = IEmployeeCoWorker;
  public
    function IEmployeeCoWorker: IEmployee;
    function CoWorker: TEmployee;
  end;

function TEmployee.IEmployeeCoWorker: IEmployee;
begin
  result := CoWorker;
end;
```

Of course, this will complicate the code, but if it actually is what you need...

Comment: Tested and working. Thanks Uwe for having provided a solution to the question - Thu I suspect the root cause of the question to be somewhere in bad design land (tighly coupled classes preventing to be used by an external component without reimporting the whole project)...

Answer (score 3):

> are the implementing class methods forced to return interfaces?

No, but implementations are forced to match the signatures of the interface definitions.

> is there a way to return objects?

Yes, if you declare the interface accordingly.

```
type
  IEmployee = interface
    function CoWorker: TEmployee;
  end;
```

Comment: The last point renders the whole interface useless. If you bind the interface to a specific implementation, there's no reason to use the interface in the first place...

Comment: @Smasher so that would imply there's no reason for INTA* interfaces to exist in `Toolsapi`, and they are useless.

Comment: TOndrej: I don't know these interfaces, but where's the point of having an "abstract" emplyoee when it's coworkers are "concrete" employees? Any other implementation of `IEmployee` is practically impossible.

Comment: @TOndrej: as precised in the question, IEmployee knowns nothing about any implementing class. Your first point is what I was expecting also, but even when declaring a method that returns an object compliant to the interface signature, it is not accepted by the compiler.

Comment: @Smasher Whether there is a point depends on context which is not clear from the information provided. I just answered the questions.

Comment: @user315561 The compiler issue is just a matter of scope. You can  include the unit where the implementation is declared in your uses clause, or if it's the same unit, use a forward declaration.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you wish for the `CoWorker` function to return `IEmployee`, for the benefit of clients of this interface.

However, the implementation code sometime has a valid reason to access the implementing object. Of course doing so does create a coupling that may be undesirable.

As of Delphi 2010 you are able to use the `as` operator to gain access to the implementing object.

```
var
  EmpIntf: IEmployee;
  EmpImp: TEmployee;
...
  EmpImp := EmpIntf as TEmployee;
```

Beware that you are now subverting the lifetime management of the object. If you access `EmpImp` after the interface reference has gone to zero, then you are in trouble.

Finally, I would comment that using such an approach has the whiff of bad design. It is usually better to find an approach that does not us `as` in this way.

Comment: I agree that the core reason of my request is certainly bad design (or at least, not enough loosely coupled classes between TEmployee and used units). Will certainly ask another question on OO design aspects.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi does not support [covariant return types.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type) So this has nothing to do with interfaces but is simply a restriction of the language itself.

Normally this is not a problem though, since clients normally should use `IEmployee` and should not care about the specific type of the coworkers. You have to provide more details (probably in a new question) why you need the specific type.

If you use interface reference-counting, you have even more reasons to only use interface type references, since mixing interface and object references can mess up the reference counting.

Comment: In the real application, IEmployee provides only a very limited set of TEmployee public functions (and I dont want to extend the interface to all public functions of TEmployee). So it seems legitimate to return a TEmployee which is much more complete that a IEmployee, and is compliant to interface requirements. I understand from your point that this is purely technical limitation, not OO bad practice?

Comment: @user315561 Why are you using an interface at all in that case?

Comment: @David: Loosely coupling between this class and an external component (in a separate package) that uses only a few public methods of this class. I cant simply import the class unit in the package because of too many, unneeded, dependencies.

Comment: @user OK, I can understand that. I really urge you to expand the question to include all the detail given in the comments.

Comment: Marked as usefull as Delphi does not really provide a way to return an object when an interface is required by the interface method (although Uwe proposed a workaround)

Answer (score 1):

If you are defining an interface function that returns an interface, why would you want to return an object in the implementation?

I believe that you only don't know how to implement "function CoWorker: IEmployee". If that's the problem, here is a simple solution:

```
TEmployee = class(TInterfacedObject, IEmployee)
public
  function CoWorker: IEmployee;
end;

function TEmployee.CoWorker: IEmployee;
begin
  Result := TEmployee.Create;
end;
```

BTW, you should derive interface-implementing objects from TInterfacedObject, not from TObject.

[EDIT]

As for your clarification - can't you define a small public interface for TEmployee and then derive this class from both interfaces? Like this:

```
type
  IEmployeePublic = ...
  IEmployee = ...

  TEmployee = class(TInterfacedObject, IEmployee, IEmployeePublic)
    function CoWorker: IEmployeePublic;
  end;
```

Comment: Regarding `TInterfacedObject`: Do this only if you want reference counting for your objects. In this case, make sure that you do not mix object and interface references.

Comment: +1 for "you should derive interface-implementing objects from TInterfacedObject"

Comment: For point 1, please see comment done to Smasher. Regarding ref counting, I need pure interface without ref counting and disabled it in TEmployee. Any advise with this new context?

Comment: Well, even in this case, CoWorker returns an interface. Based on current answers, it seems simply not possible do what is described, except with painfull workarounds. Thanks anyway :)